# how to acces object of memcached in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, memcached

what i need

- i need to access the object of memcahe in ci.

code snippet

```
class Cache_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() 
{
            parent::__construct ();
            $this->load->model('memcache_model'); 
            $m = new Memcached();
             $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
        $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'file'));
}

     // function that works

     public function getCatLevelInfo($cat_id, $cat_index)
{
    $Data = array();
  $m = new Memcached();
 $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
 $cat_info = $m->get($cat_index.$cat_id);
}

 }


  // function that don"t works



public function getCatLevelInfo($cat_id, $cat_index)
{
    $Data = array();

 $cat_info = $this->get($cat_index.$cat_id);
}
```

- i want to acces $m object that intialized in contructor.
- i have tried to access using this but im geting 500x htp repsonse code.
- any suggestion are most welcome.
- on printing object $m response is 1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your `$m` as global var try

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Ilan Hasanov
 * Date: 1/7/2016
 * Time: 1:02 PM
 */
class Cache_model extends CI_Model {

    private $m = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('memcache_model');
        $this->m = new Memcached();
        $this->m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
        $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'file'));
    }

    // function that works

    public function getCatLevelInfo($cat_id, $cat_index)
    {
        $cat_info = $this->m->get($cat_index.$cat_id);
        var_dump($cat_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2818060 glad i could help!